# WinSCP: see progress while upload/download file

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I use the WinSCP .NET Library to upload/download files from a SFTP server by using `PutFiles(..)` and `GetFiles(..)`.

Is there a way to see the progress while uploading/downloading files of this server? So for example, to get the percentage of the file-size, which is already downloaded.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [`FileTransferProgress`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress) event on the `Session` class of the [WinSCP library](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

You just have to register for that event and then update your UI from within that handler:

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Will continuously report progress of transfer
    session.FileTransferProgress += SessionFileTransferProgress;

    /* Down / upload code here */
}

void SessionFileTransferProgress(object sender, FileTransferProgressEventArgs e)
{
    // Print transfer progress
    Console.Write("\r{0} ({1:P0})", e.FileName, e.FileProgress);
}
```

Please note that `FileTransferProgressEventArgs.Side` enables you to tell if the event args are for an upload or a download. Other properties contain information about speed of transfer, the file currently transferred etc...

Here's the complete doc for it: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress

*Edit:* the event is called at the beginning of each new transfer (file) and then at most once a second for each transfer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Next question is: in which interval get this function called during an download/upload? Or is there a possibility to set the interval?

Comment: The documentation link I provided states "The event is raised, when starting transfer of every file, and then at most once a second for duration of the transfer."

Comment: Ah sry didn't see.. Thanks for your answers!